# LibRTMP Include and Install

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a visual studio solution in C++.

https://github.com/jp9000/OBS/blob/master/librtmp/librtmp.vcxproj

I was hoping to get some guidance from you regarding it's setup.

Firstly, i am using Visual Studio 2012. I opened the project in VS2012 and changed the toolset to v11.0 and built the solution successfully. So it builds fine in VS2012 with v11.0. Check.

So, there is a lib file or the project file.

I have a current application that i have created. Into this solution, i have added the Rtmp project again with the toolset changed to v11.0.

Add project to solution.
1) Add the librtmp project into the solution.
2) librtmp has been added to frameworks and references.
3) Make my main project depend on the librtmp project.
4) Added #include "rtmp.h" to my code.

Or add lib file.
1) Added to Additional Include directories. (../../OBS-master/librtmp)
2) Added to Linker -> Input -> Additional Library directories. (../../OBS-master/librtmp/DEBUG) i.e. where the lib file is.
3) Added librtmp.lib to Additional Dependancies under Linker -> Input
4) Added #include "rtmp.h" to my code.

Everything builds fine. However, when i attempt to instantiate an RTMP object.

```
RTMP *r;
char uri[]="rtmp://localhost:1935/live/desktop";
r= RTMP_Alloc();
```

When i now build, with the includes AND the function calls from rtmp i get a number of errors including LNK2120 and LNK2005. Error list is attached in helpful.

Any ideas on this? I would really appreciate it if you were able to recall any issues you may have had with this library or you could offer a strategy i could try to resolve this issue?

Alternatively there is this. But does this not just install an application? Will it let me include it into my code?

Info from site page. http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/

```
As of 2.2 the main protocol code is now available in its own library, librtmp. This library is licensed under LGPL so it may be used freely in other applications. As of 2.3 the library may also be built as a shared library, not just a static library
```

Regards,

Daniel

ERRORS

Error   118 error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\Debug\VisionBase.exe   VisionBase
Error   89  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj)  VisionBase
Error   85  error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) VisionBase
Error   86  error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) VisionBase
Error   87  error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) VisionBase
Error   99  error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)  VisionBase
Error   97  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(errmode.obj)    VisionBase
Error   94  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj)   VisionBase
Error   95  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj)   VisionBase
Error   92  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj)   VisionBase
Error   93  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj)   VisionBase
Error   78  error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)    VisionBase
Error   74  error LNK2005: __calloc_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj)    VisionBase
Error   79  error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)    VisionBase
Error   75  error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(wsetloca.obj)   VisionBase
Error   77  error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj)    VisionBase
Error   96  error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj)    VisionBase
Error   73  error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj)    VisionBase
Error   80  error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)    VisionBase
Error   81  error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)    VisionBase
Error   90  error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) VisionBase
Error   91  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) VisionBase
Error   83  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj)  VisionBase
Error   100 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)  VisionBase
Error   84  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj)  VisionBase
Error   101 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)  VisionBase
Error   88  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj)   VisionBase
Error   82  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)    VisionBase
Error   98  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) VisionBase
Error   76  error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)    VisionBase
Error   104 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12 referenced in function _RTMP_Connect0  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   105 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function _RTMPSockBuf_Close    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   106 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__connect@12 referenced in function _RTMP_Connect0   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   114 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gethostbyname@4 referenced in function _add_addr_info  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   107 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htonl@4 referenced in function _HandShake  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   108 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 referenced in function _add_addr_info  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   109 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__inet_addr@4 referenced in function _add_addr_info  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   110 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ntohl@4 referenced in function _HandShake  C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   111 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__recv@16 referenced in function _RTMPSockBuf_Fill   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   112 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__send@16 referenced in function _RTMPSockBuf_Send   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   113 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__setsockopt@20 referenced in function _RTMP_Connect0    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   116 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 referenced in function _RTMP_Connect0    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   115 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSASetLastError@4 referenced in function _RTMP_Read    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase
Error   117 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSASocketW@24 referenced in function _RTMP_Connect0    C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\VisionBase\librtmp.lib(rtmp.obj)   VisionBase

Comment: @SirDarius Any help available with this?

Comment: @Dhruva Any help available with this?

Comment: @Weekend Any help available with this?

Comment: @Dacto Any help available with this?